# Bitwise operation to get 1 if both are 0

Tags: bit-manipulation

I'd need to perform a bitwise operation (or a serie) so that:

```
0 1 = 0
1 1 = 1
1 0 = 0
```

so far AND (&) works fine but I also need that

```
0 0 = 1
```

and here AND (&) is not the correct one.

I'm using it in a jquery grep function that reads:

```
jQuery.grep(json, function (e, index) {
            return (e.value & (onoff << 3)) != 0;
        });
```

where onoff could be either 1 or 0 and e.value is a representation of a 4 bits string (i.e. could be "1001"). In this above example I'm testing first bit on the left (<< 3).

Can this be done with a serie of AND, OR, XOR?

Comment: There was an other answer (was deleted) that you need simply equality `==` operator, is it fine for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just `XNOR(a, b)`, which is equal to `NOT(XOR(a, b))`, i.e. exclusive OR with the output inverted. In C and C-like languages this would be:

```
!(a ^ b)
```

or in your specific case:

```
return !((e.value >> 3) ^ onoff);
```

Having said that, you could just test for equality:

```
return (e.value >> 3) == onoff;
```

Comment: OP asked for only AND, OR, and XOR. NOT is apparently not an option :-) I can't think of a way...

Comment: @Celada: you can use `XOR` to implement `NOT` (`NOT(a)` == `XOR(a, 1)`), or you can just test for equality.

Comment: @PaulR oh yeah. XOR with a constant. Thanks. I was trying to come up with something using only a and b :-)

Answer (score 0):

This looks roughly like XOR which has the following results table:

```
0 0 = 0
0 1 = 1
1 0 = 1
1 1 = 0
```

Now you want to have the opposite, meaning that you want `1` if both inputs are the same value. And this leads us to `NOT XOR`

```
0 0 = 1
0 1 = 0
1 0 = 0
1 1 = 1
```